# Serve different files depending on the browser language

Tags: nginx

Assuming I have a file `en/index.html` and a file `de/index.html` I'd like to serve the `de/index.html` file to users who have German as their default language setup in their browser and to all others I'd like to serve the `en/index.html` file.

How can I do this within the means of the normal nginx configuration?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/accept_language/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this:

```
set $first_language $http_accept_language;
if ($http_accept_language ~* '^(.+?),') {
  set $first_language $1;
}

set $language_suffix 'en';
if ($first_language ~* 'de') {
  set $language_suffix 'de';
}

location / {
  try_files $uri/$language_suffix/index.html $uri $uri.html;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's other way to do this but it has some drawbacks too:

```
map $http_accept_language $index_page {
    default /index.html;

    "~*^de" /index.de.html;
    "~*^fr" /index.fr.html;
}
```

Pros: no if's (if's are evil), less code.

Cons: map can only be used inside `http { }` block so regexp matching will happen for all sites, not just the current one.